# Transferring results of Google Scholar search to My Profile

Tags: publications, google-scholar

Searching Google Scholar I find thousands of references, mostly to my poetry, but also to my articles and books.  Is there any way of transferring some of these articles, books, and poems to "My Profile" without typing each in separately? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as i recall from using this feature, once you verify your email, there is an "import all" button to collate the works, and way to choose from among them, if you care to do so.

Comment: Can you please expand a bit?

Comment: google's process of setting up a scholar account takes a couple of steps: verify email and collect references. the interface uses the word "step" to refer to them. in the latter there is a picker which lists and can link some or all of what google thinks are your articles. i'm not sure if it is exactly the same as what happens by using the "add" button, but it looks similar. i can't see the original configuration any longer since i already linked my articles.